# Not sending correct header in netuno

Tags: javascript, java, cors, fetch

I have a backend developed in [netuno](https://doc.netuno.org/docs/api/header/) with api in java, and I want to send a pdf, I have no errors sending an excel, but for some reason I'm not getting it with pdf, my frontend is with react and redux.

The pdf is working when tested in postman (and yes, I know that in postman there are no cors problems), 
In the browser if I send a corrupted pdf it is sent to the frontend but if the pdf has the right data it no longer passes in the cors.

I've already put the settings on the server side to receive the correct headers

```
_header.response.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
_header.response.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS')
_header.response.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Expires, Cache-Control, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0, Pragma')
_header.response.set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
```

On the java side the pdf is going with the following headers

```java
   HttpServletResponse res = proteu.getServletResponse();
    res.setHeader("Expires", "0");
    res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    res.setHeader("Pragma", "public");

    res.setContentType("application/pdf");

    res.setContentLength(baos.size());

    OutputStream out = res.getOutputStream();
    baos.writeTo(out);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
```

My fetch call is like this right now:

```
import fetch from "cross-fetch";
const FileSaver = require("file-saver");
const qs = require("qs");

fetch("myEndPoint", {
  headers: {
    accept: "application/pdf",
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  },
  referrerPolicy: "no-referrer-when-downgrade",
  method: "POST",
  mode: "no-cors",
  body: qs.stringify({
    ...action.value
  })
})
  .then(resp => resp.blob())
  .then(blob =>
    FileSaver.saveAs(
      blob,
      "myPdf" +
        new Date(Date.now())
          .toLocaleString()
          .replace(new RegExp("/", "g"), "")
          .split(",")[0] +
        ".pdf"
    )
  );
```

when I execute the code in the browser, that's the way it is:

```
fetch("myEndPoint", {
  credentials: "omit",
  headers: { accept: "application/pdf", "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "sec-fetch-mode": "cors" },
  referrer: "http://localhost:3000/foo",
  referrerPolicy: "no-referrer-when-downgrade",
  body:
    "myData=foo",
  method: "POST",
  mode: "cors"
});
```

And I get the following error code:

```
Access to fetch at 'myEndPoint' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

which is strange, considering that all other calls work except this one, and the only difference is the type of document I get.

I have no error on the backend side.

why is chrome editing the `mode: "no-cors"` for `"mode: "cors"` ??

if I try to use "sec-fetch-mode: no-cors" in the fetch call header chrome answers:

```
Refused to set unsafe header "sec-fetch-mode"
```

Comment: should your contentType be "pdf" or at least a blob like ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in `HttpServletResponse`, when you use this on the netuno, it rewrites the header options, so I wasn't sending my previously configured settings, so the correct way to do this is as follows:

```
BaseService service = new BaseService(proteu, hili);

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
//my pdf code
service.getHeader().contentTypePDF();
service.getHeader().noCache();
service.getOut().write(baos.toByteArray());
```